# Unknown variance in a normal means model

Tags: nonparametric, regularization

I have data that I would like to model as Normal Means, i.e. with $X_i \sim \mathcal N(\theta_i,\sigma^2)$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n$, and I want an estimator of $\theta = (\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_i)$ that minimizes mean squared error. Typically, in this setting, we would use the James-Stein estimator (which is not minimax admissible, but does strictly dominate the MLE estimator when $\sigma^2$ is known)
$$\hat\theta^{JS} = \left(1 - \frac{(n-2)\sigma^2}{||X||^2}\right)X$$
Unfortunately, this is not possible here because we do not know $\sigma^2$. I have two related questions:

1. I am trying to convince my colleague that it is not possible to estimate $\sigma^2$ with only this much information, as there are more parameters than data. I wanted to confirm that this is correct.
2. In the absence of any additional information, is it possible to come up with an estimator that strictly dominates the MLE estimator in terms of risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting question, for which I do not have a definite or definitive answer. Two points:

1. The shape of the most standard James-Stein estimator
   $$\delta(\mathbf{x})=\left(1-\frac{(p-2)\sigma^2}{||\mathbf{x}||^2} \right)\mathbf{x}$$is linked with the fact that the maximal shrinkage associated with the domination of $$\delta_0(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}$$cannot exceed $2(p-2)\sigma^2$. This means that a fixed amount of shrinkage cannot work towards domination results for *all* values of $\sigma$.
2. The more general domination results that I know, including one for spherically symmetric location distributions I established in my PhD thesis in 1987 ([see Theorem 2.8.1 in my book](http://amzn.to/2kxykkw)), require at least three extra-dimensions to the $n$ $x_i$'s for the estimation of $\sigma^2$.